# Add a span tag to certain characters in a string with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have output from a CMS where I need to add a style to a certain character in the string. For instance, my output is:

```
 <div class="date">12 // 14 // 2013</div>
```

How can I add:

```
<span style="slashColor">
```

to the two double slashes so that my result would be:

```
<div class="date">12 <span class="slashColor">//</span> 14 <span class="slashColor">//</span> 2013</div>
```

Comment: And what have you tried? Why not do it with server side code?

Comment: Collect up the HTML inside the date div. Modify it to have the new span tags and put it back.

Comment: As long as you know that the double-slashes will occur in `.date` objects, you can use jQuery to iterate through them with `$(".date")` and replace each occurrence of `//` with `<span class="slashColor">//</span>`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var original = $('.date').text();
var new_version = original.split('//').join('<span class="slashColor">//</span>');
$('.date').html(new_version);
```

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gZBrk/)

**If you have many div like the example you posted, you can use this:**

```
$('.date').each(function () {
    var original = $(this).text();
    var new_version = original.split('//').join('<span class="slashColor">//</span>');
    $(this).html(new_version)
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gZBrk/1/)

Comment: @Sergio hey Sergio , could you please let me know how do I split string by vertical  pixel size  from top for example each 200 px add a break span , thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('date');
for (var i = 0, e; e = elements[i++]; ) {
   e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace(/\/\//g, '<span class="slashColor">//</span>');
}
```

or the `jQuery` way:

```
$('.date').each(function () {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/\/\//g, '<span class="slashColor">//</span>'));
}
```